# Multiple selection checkbox values

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm having trouble getting my var to accept more than one input.

When I select one checkbox, it shows me the value, however, when I select anymore I got an `undefined` error.

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function() {
  var input= document.querySelectorAll('input#add2basket');
   var radio= document.querySelectorAll('input#hi');
    for (var j=0; j < radio.length; ++j){//loops over buttons
        radio[j].onclick = function (){// find radio button
var input = findChecked(this.name);
alert (input.value)
return false;
// determine pizza size
//var size = input.value==='1'?‘Small':(input.value==='2'?'Regular':'Large');
// determine pizza price
//var price =Number(input.getAttribute('data‐price'));
// add a ‘new’ pizza to the basket
//addToBasket(newPizza(this.name,size, price));
};
};  

function findChecked(name){
var css = 'input#hi[name="'+name+'"]';
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(css);
var checked = _.filter(inputs, function (input){
document.write('<pre>'+input.checked+'</pre>')

return input.checked;

});
return checked.length===1?checked[0]:null;
}

}
```

**HTML**

```
   <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend class="Topping">Topping</legend>

                    <ul>

                        <li class="lastset"><input class="cbox" id="hi" name=
                        "top" type="checkbox" value="1"> <label class=
                        "box">Double Cheese</label></li>

                        <li class="lastset"><input class="cbox" id="hi" name=
                        "top" type="checkbox" value="2"> <label class=
                        "box">Peppers</label></li>

                        <li class="lastset"><input class="cbox" id="hi" name=
                        "top" type="checkbox" value="3"> <label class=
                        "box">Pepperoni</label></li>

                        <li class="lastset"><input class="cbox" id="hi" name=
                        "top" type="checkbox" value="4"> <label class=
                        "box">Olives</label></li>

                        <li class="lastset"><input class="cbox" id="hi" name=
                        "top" type="checkbox" value="5"> <label class=
                        "box">Beef</label></li>

                        <li class="lastset"><input class="cbox" id="hi" name=
                        "top" type="checkbox" value="6"> <label class=
                        "box">Seafood</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
            </div><!-- end topping -->
        </form>

        <div id="actionbtn">
            <!--== action buttons==-->
            <input class="apply"  type="button" value=
            "Back To Menu"> 
            <input class="apply" name="top" id="add2basket" id="actionbtn2" type="button"
            value="Proceed">
        </div><!--==end of action buttons==-->
```

When I print the `input.checked`, it shows the selected boxes as true but where do i go from there

JavaScript solutions only please.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `id` must be unique across the whole document.

```
<li class="lastset"><input class="cbox" id="hi" name=
                    "top" type="checkbox" value="6"> <label class=
                    "box">Seafood</label></li>
```

updated code:

```
<li class="lastset"><input class="cbox" id="hi_1" name=
                    "top" type="checkbox" value="6"> <label class=
                    "box">Seafood</label></li>
```

(do this for every `li` and give each `li` its own id, if you really need an id in a `li` tag

To get all your inputs, use a different selector, like the `class`-attribute:

```
var css = 'input.cbox[name="'+name+'"]';
var radio= document.querySelectorAll('input.cbox');
```

Comment: There is no real restriction for this. Most browsers would retrieve the first `id` found.

Comment: @MichaelSazonov yet, it's still concerned as bad practice.

Comment: @Allendar of course! I just wanted to help the author to improve his answer.

Comment: the id-attribute **must** be unique. Even if it works for the first item, this is just a quirks to fight against accidents. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp Please provide more information on how it can be seen as ok.

Comment: hi mate, thanks for the quick reply, basically, i have my uni project deadline in 3days, im creating a pizza site, i've done the pizza order, im trying to do the toppings , im not that good with js but the id isnt the problem coz im not using it, im getting the value true for checking more than one box but input.value only accepts one value i think ... if that makes any sense :P

Comment: You are using the id-attribute: `var css = 'input#hi[name="'+name+'"]';` the hash means your targeting an id-tag. but as the id must be unique, you can't find all of them, only the first one. I suggest you to find your inputs by name, by class, by data-* attribute or another solution.

Comment: aha yh thats right, i just noticed, havnt slept so im abit off.can you suggest another solution

Comment: the  _.filter is working properly and providing me with a boolean value of true for any checked boxes but how do i use this information to retrieve say the value of the checkbox

Comment: I modified your selector to use the class atribute. Can you make a jsfiddle so that we can test live?

Comment: sure, im gna try that, i should say this is my first post on this website

Comment: @Zim84 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"
same error

Answer (score 0):

Just select checkboxes by class name (and don't duplicate id's):

```
window.onload = function () {
    var input = document.querySelectorAll('input#add2basket');
    var radio = document.querySelectorAll('input.cbox');

    for (var j = 0; j < radio.length; j++) {
        radio[j].onchange = function () {
            var input = findChecked(this.name);
            return false;
        };
    };

    function findChecked(name) {
        var css = 'input.cbox:checked';
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(css);
        return inputs;
    }
}
```

Pluss you can simplify selection of the checked only using `:checked` pseudo selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/BPFTp/1/

Comment: hi mate, the reason i used _.filter is because it returns an array of values, so i can check more than one box and calculate the price by adding extra properties to the input items. id like to be able to check more than one box and get their value to display. again thanks